# What are some options for a small electric water flow control valve?

Tags: plumbing, water, product-recommendation

I'm looking for an electric water valve for a DIY project. I need to be able to close it partially so as to control the water flow rate. The exact details of how to control it are not important; I'm sure I can build the necessary circuitry.

Could someone please recommend one?

The only valves I find are either huge industrial valves or unbelievably expensive (£500+) lab valves.

Comment: Found some valves for approx €80 plus delivery at http://www.clippard.com/store/byo_electronic/byo_proportional_valves.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *proportional valve* and they're typically not cheap.  Here's a [series that should do what you want](http://www.ascovalve.com/Applications/Products/ProportionalControl.aspx) from ASCO, and I was able to find it for sale [online](http://part-s-mart.com/asco-sd8202g7v-1-4_proportional-vlv-0-24vdc.html) for US$316 (as of today).  I'm not sure if that price includes the PWM controller module or not, or how necessary that module is.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for this. Spent another hour searching knowing the proper name for these valves, and they are indeed expensive (in addition to being rare and hard to find). I think I'm best off grabbing a cheap tap-style valve, a couple of metal gears and a strong stepper motor...

Comment: That would definitely qualify as doing it yourself!